# How effective is text generation?

Tags: nlp, text-generation, nlg

I have implemented some basic models like composing a poem using the dataset of poems. But the results were not that good in general. I want to make a model that could write an essay for me. One strong motivation for making this essay writing model is that it would help me to escape my tedious and useless college assignments. But before I proceed and hope for making such a human-like model that could write an essay for me, I wanted to ask whether such a model is even possible to make in the first place?

Comment: If you're interested in this, you should absolutely try, but I'd recommend experimenting with existing public models before trying something from scratch yourself.  This is because some of the best current language models are extremely expensive to train [1], and yield results that (in my opinion) produce good sentences, decent paragraphs, but probably bad essays.  Sees some examples here (https://www.gwern.net/GPT-3) and judge for yourself.  [1] gpt3 is estimated to have cost over 4.5 million dollars to train (https://lambdalabs.com/blog/demystifying-gpt-3/).

Comment: You should try this game. It creates stories based on user inputs. I haven't seen anything better than this                                     https://play.aidungeon.io/main/home

Comment: Learning how to properly train a model capable of writing realistic essays would require: (1) that you acquire quite a lot of knowledge about machine learning and natural language processing (2) that you spend a lot of time and computing power to implement, train and test the model. This is definitely more work than writing your own essays, but you can try ;)

Comment: @bogovicj I find GTP3 quite impressive. Is there a way by which I can load the GTP 3 model in my python code and then perform fine tuning on it?

Comment: @DwipDalal, as of today the answer is no.  You need to use openAI's api: see  https://openai.com/blog/gpt-3-apps/ and https://openai.com/blog/openai-api/, but there are other public models

Comment: okay. Thank you.